# Binding private property in [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-ngmodel, two-way-binding

How to bind `private` property in Angular 4?

```
export class newItem{
  private id: number;
  private description: string;
  private insertDate: any;

  get getId() : number {
    return this.id;
  }
  set setId(name : number) {
    this.id = name;
  }
  get getDescription() : string {
    return this.description;
  }
  set setDescription(description : string) {
    this.description = description;
  }
  get getInsertDate() : string {
    return this.insertDate;
  }
  set setInsertDate(insertDate : string) {
    this.insertDate = insertDate;
  }
```

Here

it throws `Cannot assign to 'getInsertDate' because it is a constant or a read-only property.`

Comment: Why do your getters and setters have different names? You should just have `get insertDate` and `set insertDate`, and give the private backing property a different name (`_insertDate`, by convention). That said, given that your getters and setters don't do anything, *why do you have them at all?*

Comment: beacuse otherwise I got error `duplicate identifier`

Comment: I think you should read http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors again.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to change it to:

```
private _id: number;
  get id() : number {
    return this.id;
  }
  set id(name : number) {
    this.id = name;
  }
```

Comment: Again, in that case, **there's no point having a getter and setter**.

Comment: Why is that? Can you tell me?

Comment: Why do you think? Because they *don’t do anything*. You’ve added multiple lines of code and associated cognitive overhead for *no benefit whatsoever*. The great thing about transparent ways to control access to an attribute, like these accessors and Python’s properties, is that you can *leave them out completely* until you actually need them to do something.

Answer (score 1):

### Just bind the property directly :

[Demo in this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/igB02FjJlwJnxqjzHXx2?p=preview)

Template :

```
<input [(ngModel)]="testVar" #textBox type="text"> 
<p>This is the value of testVar : {{testVar}}</p>
```

Component :

```
 export class MyComponent {
     private testVar: string = "Test this";
 }
```

---

1. if you want double-binding and use getters and setters, then **your get and set must have the same name** (the name used in the template)
2. **properties don't need to be public** in component to allow data binding with `ngModel`. They can perfectly be private.
3. and as already said in other answers, in your situation **you don't need getter and setters at all!**.

Best to avoid unnecessary code, for your own mind sanity !

If you are worried about encapsulation, don't be : think of your template as part of your component. It's absolutely ok for the template to use the components private fields (and without going through get/set accessors, unless you want it)

### If you are using Ahead Of Time (AOT) compilation

The bound variable should be public, unfortunately.

Comment: I just noticed this old answer of mine was upvoted, I'm just adding a detail I since learned : You will have to use a public variable / getter to bind in the template if you are using AOT.